# Flattening Nested Data Structure in Sequelize Query Result

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm working on a Node.js application using Sequelize as my ORM, and I'm encountering an issue with flattening a nested data structure in the result of a Sequelize query.

I have a Sequelize query that retrieves user details along with their associated roles and permissions.

The result of this query `(user)` contains nested data, particularly the `permissions` array within the `role` object, which is nested within the user_details object. I need to flatten this nested `permissions` array and include the `module.name` as `module_name` within each `permission` object directly in the `user_details` object.

User table has `role_id`
Permissions table has `role_id` and `module_id`

I have tried set to attributes empty in the role level but it is throwing error
`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'permissions')`

```
// Create a findOptions object for findByEmail
        const findOptions = {
            attributes: {
                include: [[Sequelize.col('role.name'), 'role_name']]
            },
            include: [
                {
                    as: 'role',
                    model: Role,
                    required: true,
                    attributes: ['id'],
                    include: [
                        {
                            required: true,
                            as: 'permissions',
                            model: Permission,
                            attributes: ['id', 'read', 'create', 'update', 'delete', 'module_id'],
                            include: [
                                {
                                    as: 'module',
                                    model: Module,
                                    required: true,
                                    attributes: ['name']
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        };

        // Check if the email is already associated with another account
        const user = await this.userRepository.findByEmail(payload.email, findOptions);
```

Comment: You could possibly try to play with `raw` and `nest` options but a lot easier just to create a mapper function that converts Sequelize instances to a given view OR to use virtual props in model that will map nested collections and props into needed structure

Comment: @Anatoly, can you be able to share some examples?

Comment: Example of mapper function or a virtual model prop?

Comment: virtual model prop

Answer (score 1):

You can use a virtual field in a Sequelize model to map nested instances to the parent prop:

```js
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  // other usual model props
  ...
  permissions: {
    type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
    get() {
      // you and a check and can return an empty array here
      // if `role` and/or `permissons` is not included in the query
      return this.role.pemissions.map(x => ({
        id: x.id,
        read: x.read,
        create: x.create,
        update: x.update,
        delete: x.delete, 
        module_id: x.module_id,
        module_name: x.module.name
      }));
    },
    set(value) {
      throw new Error('Do not try to set the `permissions` value!');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: since my user table has role_id foreign key and my permissions table has same foreign key role_id. Can I create relation between user and permissions by the two foreignkeys.  It will reduce one label of include in the query

Comment: is it a good practice?

Comment: Technically you could do it using `hasMany` association but I'm not sure it's a good idea especially because it won't be a real 1:N relationship and users and permissions tables don't have `role_id` as a PK or a unique constraint.